# Can't turn off hibernate info logging

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

i am using log4j
and my configuration is as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, stdout, rootLog
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.rootLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rootLog.File=${user.home}/logs/mylog.log
log4j.appender.rootLog.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.rootLog.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.rootLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rootLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n

# Control/Limit integrated frameworks logging messages

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF
log4j.logger.org.springframework=OFF
```

although i am turning off the root logger and the hibernate logging

i am still seeing info in the console from:

```
2099 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory
2440 [main] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport
3239 [main] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter
```

how to stop that, please advise, thanks.

**UPDATE:** logging jars/dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>

            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
             <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
             <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
             <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
             <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>

        </dependency>
```

Comment: well solved it by using configuration in this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711755/hibernate-log4j-and-slf4j/8712210#8712210

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not really what your log4j config is. The output you've listed doesn't match either of the conversion patterns you showed in the config file. It's using some other configuration.

**Update:** Based on your updated question, if you're using an SLF4J Logger, then you aren't even using Log4J because you're using the slf4j-simple binding, which "outputs all events to System.err. Only messages of level INFO and higher are printed" per the [SLF4J manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#binding). To use Log4J, you have to use the slf4j-log4j12 binding.

Comment: any ideas how to turn that off ?

Comment: Yes, find the right log4j config file and turn it off there. If you set the `log4j.debug` system property, then log4j will tell you what file it's using for configuration.

Comment: where to set this property log4j.debug ?

Comment: and BTW, i only have one log4j.properties file, then what right log4j file you are talking about then ?

Comment: is there's any additional configuration needs to be done to use `slf4j-log4j12` after adding it's maven dependency, because after i added it's dependency and removed `slf4j-simple` i got an exception.

Comment: here it is:  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple; `

Comment: Check the [SLF4J docs](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch), specifically: "mixing different versions of slf4j-api.jar and SLF4J binding can cause problems. For example, if you are using slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar, then you should also use slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar, using slf4j-simple-1.5.5.jar will not work."

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find out which log4j config file it is using.  You can turn on debug on log4j, as a -D parameter when you run Java, and it will tell you.